# How can I move in-app downloads (e.g. Coursera videos from Coursera app) onto my SD card without rooting the phone?

Tags: sd-card

I've just got my first Android phone and I bought a 64GB micro-SD card so I can download videos from apps like Lynda, Coursera and Khan Academy. I've moved my apps to my SD card but when I download the videos in the app itself, it appears they are being saved to the phone memory, not the SD card like I want them to. Is there any way around this?

Here's the fix:

I didn't see the option in the Lynda app for some reason but it's there.

For those who are wondering, open the Lynda app and go Home (top left) > Settings (bottom of menu) > Storage Location > Set to external.

Similarly, in Coursera, go into your home page, tap the profile silhouette on the top left > My downloads > Menu (top right, vertically aligned dots) > Storage Location > Select your SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the application in question, typically there should be an option within the app itself along the lines of "Save to External Storage" which should save the videos to your SD Card

I know Udemy has this option as I have it set to Save to External Storage on my Note 3

HTH

Comment: Yep, this did it. I didn't see the option in the Lynda app for some reason but it's there.

For those who are wondering, open the Lynda app and go Home (top left) > Settings (bottom of menu) > Storage Location > Set to external.

Similarly, in Coursera, go into your home page, tap the profile silhouette on the top left > My downloads > Menu (top right, vertically aligned dots) > Storage Location > Select your SD card.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)